# Morphisms of presheaves from presheaf F to sheaf G

Tags: algebraic-geometry

There is the lemma that states that if f,g : F -> G are morphisms of sheaves, such that $\forall x \in X, f_x = g_x$, then f = g.

Is this true also if f,g : F -> G are morphisms of pre-sheaves, with G a sheaf (F pre-sheaf)?

Comment: Yes: for each $U$, $s \in F(U)$, the stalks of $f(U)s$ and $g(U)s$ are the same and since $G$ is a sheaf, $f(U)s=g(U)s$.

Comment: Do you mean the germs $(f(U)s)_x = (g(U)s)_x \forall x \in X$ are equal? (where $(f(U)s)$ is a section of G) Can you explain the stalks,  when you say stalks, aren't you looking at $G_x$? Aren't the elements of the stalk $G_x$ germs?

Comment: You can do it by hand as Mindlack suggests, or use the fact that $f,g$ factor through the sheafification of $F$

Comment: @Max Neat observation! Actually, we are also using the fact that $\alpha_x: F_x \to F_x^a$ is an epimorphism since then, $f_x = g_x$ implies the unique morphism from sheafification from $f$ := $\theta_x^{(f)}$ equals the unique morphism from sheafification from $g$, i.e. $\theta_x^{(f)} \circ \alpha_x = \theta_x^{(g)} \circ \alpha_x \Rightarrow \theta_x^{(f)} = \theta_x^{(g)}$

Comment: Well $F_x \to F_x^a$ is an isomorphism, but you are correct that we use some information about it

Comment: @Max Well actually, since you mentioned it, I was a bit confused about this in class;  can you explain why $\alpha_x: F_x \to F_x^a$ is an isomorphism, and how about $\alpha: F \to F^a$, is this invertible? Because the way the morphism is constructed for a section $s$ sent to the associated map $x \mapsto s_x$, it looks invertible, and for sure suggests a natural candidate for the inverse of the mentioned associated map.

Comment: $\alpha$ is not invertible (otherwise $F$ would always be a sheaf !). The idea for $\alpha_x$ is that any section of $F^a$ is locally a section of $F$ so $\alpha_x$ is surjective and it's injective because if $\alpha_x(s_x) = \alpha_x(t_x)$ then you can lift those to a section of $F$ in a sinilar way. If that's not enough you should open another post for that specific question (and post the link here in the comments)

Comment: @Max Thanks, that's enough info, and ressembles similar proofs seen in class, much appreciated!

Comment: @Max One more question if that is ok, so an isomorphism of presheaves between a presheave and a sheaf implies that the presheave is actually a sheaf?

Comment: Yes, you should try to prove it as an exercise